# Checking if a number is power of 2 or not

Tags: java, interview-questions, integer

This is my solution in Java and I need your opinion:

```
public class Main {

  /**
   * 
   */

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = in.nextInt();
    in.close();

    if (isPowerOfTwo(number)) {
      System.out.println("yes");
    } else {
      System.out.printf("no");
    }
  }

  private static boolean isPowerOfTwo(int number) {

    if (number % 2 != 0) {
      return false;
    } else {

      for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++) {

        if (Math.pow(2, i) == number) return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: But $$ 1 = 2^0 $$

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I'm not asking for answers, I'm asking for my code to be reviewed.

Comment: @Egek92 You should not change the code up for review after posting it, because that distorts the existing answers.

Comment: Please don't invalidate answers by editing your code.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### `try-with-resources`

Since Java 7, you should use [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) on your `Scanner` for safe and efficient handling of the underlying I/O resource:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        int number = scanner.nextInt();
        // other operations
    }
}
```

#### Mathematical approach

You may want to consider using a [faster mathematical approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two#Fast_algorithm_to_check_if_a_positive_number_is_a_power_of_two) to test if the number is a *positive* power of two or not...

```
boolean result = number > 0 && ((number & (number - 1)) == 0);
```

\$1\$ is technically a power of two: \$2^0\$

Comment: Good point on the try with resources, but we probably don't want to close System.in at all.

Comment: @bowmore meant to span the  entirety of the `main()` class... :)

Comment: I take it, from the smiley, you're just dodging the question :p

Comment: On the mathematical approach, how about using [Integer.bitCount()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount(int))?

Comment: @JollyJoker that seems to fit for the OP too, you should post that as a separate answer. :)

Comment: @h.j.k. OK, done

Answer (score 35):

There's actually a bit hack for this :

```
private static boolean isPowerOfTwo(int number) {

    return number > 0 && ((number & (number - 1)) == 0);

}
```

(ref : [Bit Twiddling hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2))

This exploits the fact, that in binary notation a power of two is a 1 followed by a number of 0's, and the number just below is all 1's equal to that number of 0's :

```
  100000000 // number
& 011111111 // number - 1
-----------
  000000000
```

Comment: Wouldn't `number > 0` be a better approach?

Comment: How is this hack? It's the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: @MatthewRock The technique is a hack because it uses extra details specific to the context of the calculation to perform the work: namely, the binary representation of the number. A non-hackish technique would be a numerical technique independent of the representation of the number (perhaps: `if(n % 2 != 0) return n == 1; return isPow2(n/2);`). The method only works if the number is internally represented in binary. Granted, that's a rather safe assumption for computers. Also, calling it a "hack" is not necessarily pejorative.

Comment: @MatthewRock it's not my choice of words actually, I'm just using the term since the site I refer to calls them hacks.

Comment: @Egek92 yes it would, post edited

Comment: alternative solution: `Integer.bitCount(number) == 1` ... also much more intuitive...

Answer (score 14):

1. It incorrectly returns `false` when the input is `1`. \$2^0 = 1\$
2. Looping up to `number` is very inefficient. For example if `number` is two billion, it'll loop two billion times, but you'd only need about `log2(number)` iterations, or simply hardcode the range 0 to 30, since the input is a 32-bit integer.
3. Mixing floating point and integers is difficult to reason about. In this case it's no problem, since every 32-bit integer is exactly representable as `double`, but using `long` the code would compile and return incorrect results, since `Math.pow(2,62) == Long.MAX_VALUE / 2`.

   I'd use bit-shifts instead.

Comment: `1 << i` and `1L << i` will be far faster than `Math.pow(2, i)`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc When going for performance, you'd use the classic bithack the other answers mention. My preference for shifting integers instead of floating point operations is mainly based on doing the conceptually right thing, and not on shaving off a few CPU cycles.

Comment: yeah my comment is on the shifting thing, not that this is a good algorithm

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the existing answers. If you want to preserve the idea of looping through powers of two, you can multiply by two at each step

```
int i=1;
while(i<number && i<Integer.MAX_VALUE/2) {
  i*=2;
}
return i == number;
```

If you want to use binary numbers you can check that the number is positive and contains exactly one one bit

```
return number > 0 && Integer.bitCount(number) == 1;
```

Note that `Integer.MIN_VALUE` has a bit count of one, so you technically need the `number > 0` check.

Comment: For the looping procedure, if `number` is more than `MAX_INT/2`, then `i` will eventually overflow, leading to wrong answers. It's better to start with `i = number` and divide by 2 until you get an odd number. Then check if `i == 1`.

Comment: @MarkH Fixed the bug. Yeah, you're probably right in that division is the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use bit manipulation, then look at the `Math.log2(x)` method, which is the reverse of `Math.pow(2, x)`.

Or alternatively repeat dividing the number by 2 until you have an odd number. If that number is 1 then the original number is a power of 2.

Comment: `while(x%2==0) x/=2`